# OpenVPN Attempting to establish TCP connection failed: Connection refused

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

So I have a server set up on my digitalOcean account and after going through the process of setting up a client, i try to connect running

> openvpn --config client.ovpn

but it shows this

> Tue May 16 14:09:21 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.1 i686-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 28 2017
>   Tue May 16 14:09:21 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.08
>   Tue May 16 14:09:21 2017 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
>   Tue May 16 14:09:21 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]:1194
>   Tue May 16 14:09:21 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
>   Tue May 16 14:09:21 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]:1194 [nonblock]
>   Tue May 16 14:09:23 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]:1194 failed: Connection refused
>   Tue May 16 14:09:23 2017 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
>   Tue May 16 14:09:23 2017 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting

My server config is:

- port 1194
- proto tcp
- dev tun
- ca ca.crt
- cert server.crt
- key server.key
- dh dh2048.pem
- server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
- ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
- push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
- push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
- push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
- keepalive 10 120
- cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
- comp-lzo
- user nobody
- group nobody
- persist-key
- persist-tun
- status openvpn-status.log
- verb 3

With everything else commented out.

My client.ovpn is:

- dev tun
- proto tcp
- remote  1194
- resolv-retry infinite
- nobind
- user nobody
- group nobody
- persist-key
- persist-tun
- ca ca.crt
- cert client1.crt
- key client1.key
- ns-cert-type server
- cipher BF-CBC
- comp-lzo
- verb 3

with everything else commented out.
I think it may have something to do with my iptable rules, but i'm not sure if I should paste below because of how long it is. If you think you would need to see to solve the problem just let me know and I'd be happy to paste it. I rather new to openvpn and just trying to learn how it works so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First look on server that is `vpn` in running state and in listen state. For first is command `systemctl status openvpn` and for listening state `netstat -atnp`. If you see something like `0.0.0.0 tcp 1194 listening` then try from pc this command `nc -v <ip_address_of_server 1194`. If you got connection, problem is setup of `openvpn` if you can not establish connection, problem is `iptables`.

Comment: So when i ran 'systemctl status openvpn' it showed it was active (with green font) so I assume that means its in running state. When I used the command 'netstat -atnp' it gave me a rather lengthy list but nothing with 0.0.0.0 tcp 1194 and nothing with the port 1194 mentioned anywhere on it. Should I still run the 'nc -v' command?

Comment: Run command. With that command you will try to connect make `tcp` connection to `vpn` on port `1194`. If you do not have connection, edit your question and put output from `iptables` and command `netstat -atnp`

Comment: when i run the 'nc -v ' command it says inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [<server ip>] 1194 (openvpn) : Connection refused 
I run this command on the vpn server correct?

Comment: To clarify, if you server is on ip `123.456.789.123`, command will be `nc -v 123.456.789.123 1194`

Comment: yes thats what i put in but it gives me the connection refused error

Comment: Then you can not make connection to server. Probably `iptables` deny traffic.

Comment: ok so im not totally sure how to configure iptables, but is there a way to allow traffic on that port over tcp

Comment: try to add `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT` on server

Comment: so i put that in and i guess it worked cause no errors popped up but when i tried the 'nc -v' command again it still gives me the same error. A couple things that i probably should have mentioned before (sorry) that im running the client on a virtual machine of fedora and when i used the command 'netstat -atnp' is showed and established connection with the server over port 22 which im assuming is ssh.

Comment: Try to make connection with `udp` protocol. `OpenVPN` by default work with `udp` protocol on port `1194`. Make connection with `nc`, command is `nc -v -u 123.456.789.123 1194`. `iptables` rule is `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT`